# How to skip `\r \n ` in string

Tags: c#

I am working on a simple converter which converts a text to another language,

suppose i have two textboxes and in 1st box you enter the word `Index` and press the convert button.
I will replace your text with this `فہرست` an alternative of `Index` in urdu language but i have a problem if you enter word `index` and gives some spaces or gives some returns then i get text of that textbox in c# like this `Index         \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n` now how can i get rid of this i want to get simple `Index` always .
Thanks for answer and please feel free to comment if you have any question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the `Trim` method if the new lines are only at the end of beginning:

```
input = input.Trim();
```

You can use [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx), if you want to remove new lines anywhere in the string:

```
// Replace line break with spaces
input = input.Replace("\r\n", " ");
// (Optionally) Combine consecutive spaces to one space (probalby not most efficient but should work)
while (input.Contains("  ")) { input = input.Replace("  ", " "); }
```

If you want to prevent newlines completely, most `TextBox` Controls have a property like `MultiLine` or similar, that, when set, prevents entering more than one line.

Comment: trim is not working if you have a word like `Index          Index`

Comment: @Smartboy Ok, then Replace will be better for this. Updated the answer.

Comment: But if you have `index\r\nindex`, the output will be `indexindex` and I'm not sure that the translation will work well.

Comment: @Steve Yes, that's true, i changed it to replace it with spaces and (optionally) combine consecutive spaces to one.

Answer (score 5):

This should suffice to remove whitespaces as defined by [Char.IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) (blanks, newlines etc)

```
string wordToTranslate = textBox1.Text.Trim();
```

however, if your textbox contains multiple words then you should use a different approach

```
string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split((char[]) null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string wordToTranslate in words)
    ExecTranslation(wordToTranslate);
```

using [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) with char[] null as separator allows to identify every whitespaces as valid word separator

Answer (score 5):

`input.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty);`

User `Replace` to remove characters from the 'inside' of the string. `Trim` removes characters only at the begining and end of string.

Answer (score 4):

Add all chars you want to ignore to the string:

```
var cleanChars = text.Where(c => !"\n\r".Contains(c));
string cleanText = new string(cleanChars.ToArray());
```

That works because string implements `IEnumerable<char>`.